# Terraformed planet orbiting a blue star

Tags: science-fiction, space, terraforming

A planet was terraformed in humanity's distant past by technologically superior beings. The planet is very similar to Earth. I understand blue stars are highly radioactive and thus don't have real habitable zones so the planet's orbit is placed where it has water available in at least its main three forms.

Because the planet has to be a very large distance from the star it has an extremely long year and seasons lasting longer than a typical lifespan.

The Question - What are the main concerns that were mitigated, including radiation, by the makers? What methods could have been used to do so?

Science based answers are preferred. Handwavium and unobtaninium elements are acceptable but not magic as this is meant to be a science fiction world. It is okay to vary the planet some as long as humans can still live somewhere on the planet without high tech being necessary.

Comment: Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are not objective and you've provided no criteria for judging a best answer. Please remember that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  BTW, the habitable zone depends very much on the planet's magnetosphere and ability to deflect charged particles.

Comment: *"Handwavium and unobtaninium elements are acceptable but not magic"* you realize those are all the same thing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is photosynthesis. A blue star would potentially not put out enough light in the correct frequencies for effective photosynthesis. That coupled with long winters would make flora a big concern. It would be better to have the planet un-tilted and in circular orbit such that there were no long seasons. Perhaps have a flora suited to low light.. or fungi.